# Nested sql insert from php

Tags: mysql, select, nested

I have a nested array in php and I'm trying to insert data into a mysql table only if a duplicate does not exist. The duplicate should only check match against the sensor_serial and dates field. I'm having no luck with DUPLICATE as the id is unique regardless of the other fields. this is the table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temps_test` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `sensor_serial` varchar(64) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `temp_c` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `dates` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `date` (`dates`)
)
```

This is my non working code. I can't seem to get it quite right.

```
foreach ($output as $k => &$v) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO temps_test (sensor_serial,temp_c,dates) VALUES ('$v[7]','$v[3]','$v[5]') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM temps_test WHERE sensor_serial='$v[7]' AND dates='$v[5]')";
    $go = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
}
```

Can this be done this way or is my approach totally off?

Comment: what do you want if `sensor_serial` already exist? still insert data or go to next record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO temps_test (sensor_serial,temp_c,dates)
VALUES ('val1','val2','val3') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sensor_serial=sensor_serial;
```

make sure to add constraint on field `sensor_serial`, example

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temps_test`
(
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `sensor_serial` varchar(64) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `temp_c` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `dates` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `date` (`dates`),
    CONSTRAINT t_uq INIQUE (`sensor_serial`)     -- <== this one
)
```

Comment: The 'dates' field is not unique. The combination of 'sensor_serial' and 'dates' is what is unique and also what I'm trying to avoid duplicated of. The 'dates' field on it's own may have duplicates.

Comment: @user1708479 so add a compound unique key constraint, eg, `CONSTRAINT t_uq INIQUE (sensor_serial, dates)`